# drop a list item into an image and show it in a text box in the corresponding area of image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image and an adjacent list side by side in a page.My aim is to drop the list item inside the image in a specific area by the user and show the list inside a text box input preferably.is there a way to do this.My code is as follows,

```
<div style={{position:'relative',marginTop:'50px',marginBottom: '200px'}} id='galleyDesign'>
    {showGalleyF1 &&
    <div>
    <img className="floatLeft" src={galley}  alt='' width="50%" height="50%"/>
    <div className='nav-menu-items sm-scrollbar'>
            <ul className='nav-menu-components-box' style={{width: "400px",marginLeft:"60px"}}>
            {
                componentData
                .map((_,index) => {
                    if(_.selected){
                        return (
                            <div
                            draggable
                            style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                            >
                            <li className='nav-menu-components active-text'>
                          <span id={"important-span"+_.id} className='nav-menu-components-title floatLeft mt-2'>
                            <img className="icon" alt='widgets' src={rubic} />
                            &nbsp;<b>{_.rollNo}</b> - &nbsp;{_.name}</span>
                          <div className='drag-reorder-widgets'>
                          </div>
                          </li>
                          </div>
                        )
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
```